# multiple webRTC connections

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, webrtc, web-worker

Can we  technically open multiple webRTC connections from a browser to a server? Or each instance of a browser can make only one single webRTC connections to a specific server?

I am thinking to use webworkers to create multiple thread from each of which establish a separate webRTC connection to a specific webRTC server.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, peer connections establishment via web-worker is not permitted. For second question, obviously you can setup multiple peer connection to a media server on the same webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely setup multiple webrtc peer connections from your page. As far as your second question goes, no need to create separate webworkers for each webrtc connection, since webrtc stack is already separating audio/video encoding/decoding and other processing on multiple threads under the cover pretty efficiently.